# Eclipse 4.6 Neon via ppa

Tags: eclipse, linux-mint

How to install Eclipse 4.6 Neon via ppa on Linux Mint 18 x64 and update it with apt-get? Newest one in repository is 3.8. I know, that I can download it from website, but I want it to be automatically updated with system, as everything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wiki, you'll need to install Neon using their installer and then follow the in-app upgrade process for later releases. They seem to be touting their installer as they best way to stay up to date at this point.

Source: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F

> ..to use Eclipse Neon IDE, you have to download a new package or use
>   the Eclipse IDE Installer from http://eclipse.org/downloads . After
>   Neon, the usual upgrade process detailed below works.

There doesn't appear to be a repo configured to automatically update using your apt.